# Can I add datepicker to HTML element with Angularjs directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I am trying to add a datepicker via an Angularjs Directive while passing the element as shown below and it's not working, but if I specify an element id, it works fine:

HTML:

```
<input id="startdate" type="text" ng-model="i.itinerary.DapartDate" date-from />
```

app.js:

Not Working:

```
travelApp.directive('dateFrom', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {

        element.datepicker({ minDate: currentTime });
        element.change(function () {
            currentTime = element.val();
        });

    }
})
```

WORKING

```
travelApp.directive('dateFrom', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {

        $("startdate").datepicker({ minDate: currentTime });
        $("startdate").change(function () {
            currentTime = $("#startdate").val();
        });

    }
})
```

Unfortunately I can not use controls ids, because I have an array of start and end dates in my itinerary list, so I need to bind this function to every newly created date element in itinerary array. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your non-working example you try to call `.datepicker` on the `element` itself, you need to make it a jQuery object first!

```
$(element).datepicker({ minDate: currentTime });
$(element).change(function () {
    currentTime = element.val();
});
```